# Null safety errors on model from quicktype

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to use a json model for my project. This is theresult I get from quicktype:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

Hisselist hisselistFromJson(String str) => Hisselist.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hisselistToJson(Hisselist data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Hisselist {
  Hisselist({
    required this.code,
    required this.data,
  });

  String code;
  List<Datum> data;

  factory Hisselist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hisselist(
        code: json["code"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "code": code,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    required this.id,
    required this.kod,
    required this.ad,
    required this.tip,
  });

  int id;
  String kod;
  String ad;
  Tip tip;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["id"],
        kod: json["kod"],
        ad: json["ad"],
        tip: tipValues.map[json["tip"]],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "kod": kod,
        "ad": ad,
        "tip": tipValues.reverse[tip],
      };
}

enum Tip { HISSE }

final tipValues = EnumValues({"Hisse": Tip.HISSE});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

I added "required at Datum class for null safety but I can not these 2 problems :

> error: Non-nullable instance field 'reverseMap' must be initialized.
> (not_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field at [myapp]
> lib/models/apis/hisselist.dart:69)
>
> error: The argument type 'Tip?' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'Tip'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [myapp]
> lib/models/apis/hisselist.dart:48)

How can I fix this? thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get null from reading json, thats why it is showing error on `tipValues.map[json["tip"]]` using bang`!` is risky, you can provide default value on null case like

```dart
tip: tipValues.map[json["tip"]]?? Tip.HISSE,
```

Or make `tip` nullable

```dart
  Tip? tip;
```

Now on `EnumValues` all item expected to be initialized, you can use `late` to promise that you will assign data before reading it
  `late Map<T, String> reverseMap;`

or better make it nullable

```dart
 Map<T, String>? reverseMap;
```

```dart
class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    return reverseMap ??= map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
  }
}
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Thank you very much. In the Datum class using "required" is a good choice or would you prefer any other methods?

Comment: I prefer using required or nullable data based on case. Required will force to assign data and mostly I use it, and nullable data can be checked before read time and useful for different case.